# Training Loss decreasing but Validation Loss is stable

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, overfitting-underfitting

I am trying to train a neural network I took from this paper https://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=10455&context=theses. See this image: [Neural Network Architechture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oG4v.png)

I am using pytorch-lightning to use multi-GPU training.

I am feeding this network 3-channel optical flows (UVC: U is horizontal temporal displacement, V is vertical temporal displacement, C represents the confidence map).

Ouputs represent the frame to frame pose and they are in the form of a vector of 6 floating values ( translationX, tanslationY, translationZ, Yaw, Pitch, Roll). Translations vary from -0.25 to 3 in meters and rotations vary from -6 to 6 in degrees.

Outputs dataset is taken from kitti-odometry dataset, there is 11 video sequences, I used the first 8 for training and a portion of the remaining 3 sequences for evaluating during training.

I trained the model for 200 epochs ( took 33 hours on 8 GPUs ).

During this training, training loss decreases but validation loss remains constant during the whole training process.

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [cv_resize((370,1242)),
     flow_transform_and_uint8_and_tensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.3973, 0.2952, 0.4500), (0.4181, 0.4362, 0.3526))])

batch_size = 8
val_data_percentage = 0.06
epochs = 200
learning_rate = 0.0001

train_dataset = FlowsAndPoses("./uvc_flows_png/train/", "./relative_poses/train/", transform)
test_dataset = FlowsAndPoses("./uvc_flows_png/test/", "./relative_poses/test/", transform)

dataset_length = test_dataset.__len__()
test_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(test_dataset,[int(dataset_length*(1-val_data_percentage)),dataset_length - int(dataset_length*(1-val_data_percentage))])
print("Train: ",train_dataset.__len__(), "   Validation: ", val_dataset.__len__())

criterion = nn.L1Loss()
class Net(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 7, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5, 2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 5, 2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, 1)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, 2)
        self.conv6 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, 1)
        self.conv7 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, 2)
        self.conv8 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, 1)
        self.conv9 = nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, 3, 2)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32768, 1024)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 6)

        self.net_relu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv5(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv6(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv7(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv8(x))
        x = self.net_relu(self.conv9(x))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = self.net_relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        running_loss = 0
        print("Training: ")
        inputs, labels = batch
        outputs = self.forward(inputs.float())
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.float())
        self.log("my_loss", loss, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def training_epoch_end(self, training_step_outputs):
        training_loss_file = open("losses/training_loss"+str(self.current_epoch)+"_"+str(self.global_step), "w")
        training_loss_file.write(str(training_step_outputs))
        training_loss_file.close()
        try:
            torch.save(self.state_dict(), "checkpoints/trained_model_epoch"+str(self.current_epoch)+".pth")
        except:
            print("error saving")

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, labels = batch
        outputs = self.forward(inputs.float())
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.float())
        self.log("val_loss", loss)
        return loss

    def validation_epoch_end(self, validation_step_outputs):
        valid_loss_file = open("losses/validation_loss"+str(self.current_epoch)+"_"+str(self.global_step), "w")
        valid_loss_file.write(str(validation_step_outputs))
        valid_loss_file.close()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
        return optimizer


autoencoder = Net()
trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], accelerator="gpu", strategy="ddp", enable_checkpointing=True, max_epochs=epochs, check_val_every_n_epoch=1)
trainer.fit(autoencoder, DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True), DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True))
```

**Zero Grad** and **optimizer.step** are handled by the pytorch-lightning library.

The results I got are in the following images:

[Training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVgpC.png)

[Validation loss during training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt988.png)

If anyone has suggestions on how to address this problem, I would really apreciate it.

Comment: Is your plan to use `test_dataset` for later? Because you are splitting up your original `test_dataset` into `test_dataset` and `val_dataset` but `val_dataset` is only 6% of your test data. I imagine that `val_dataset` contains so few samples that they are distinct from your training data. Either that, or your model is simply ovefitting to the training data (remembering frames from your training videos and is not able to generalize).

Comment: yes, I want to use test_dataset later when I get some results ( validation loss decreases ).

Comment: Yes validation dataset is taken from a different set of sequences than those used for training. But when first trained my model and I split training dataset ( sequences 0 to 7 ) into training and validation, validation loss decreases because validation data is taken from the same sequences used for training eventhough it is not the same data for training and evaluating.

Comment: So as you said, my model seems to like overfitting the data I give it. It is not learning the relationship between optical flows and frame to frame poses.